# How to fix "Error 503 Backend fetch failed" in Varnish which occurs after certain time?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, apache2, varnish

The site works fine with varnish running on the backend. But after few days it give me errors like this "Error 503 Backend fetch failed". If I restart the apache server, the site seemed to be working again! Again after few days it show me the same error! How can I debug the problem or fix it?

```
Error 503 Backend fetch failed

Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:

XID: ******

Varnish cache server
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to degub this is to run varnishlog and check which "Backend Fetches" are failing. Most likely your are passing a lot of request onto your backend and it can't cope with the load, hence it crashes.